# Es posible colocar una imagen de fondo en una tabla usando el plugin de jquery datatable?

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

he intentado de las siguientes maneras sin resultado...

... en el cuerpo de la tabla

```
<tbody background="./images/credibanco.jpg" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;">     
 <?php
 require_once '../ConsultasSW/ConsolidadoOperacionClientesSW.php';
 echo ConsolidadoOperacionClientes($_POST["v1"], $_POST['v3'], $_POST['v4']);
 ?>
```

en el div que contiene la tabla

```
<div id="operacionClientes" style="background-image: url(./images/credibanco.jpg)">
    <table id="opeClientes" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Cantidad de productos</th>                                                                    
                <th>Valor total</th>
                <th>Tipo de entrega</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Cantidad de productos</th>                                                                    
                <th>Valor total</th>
                <th>Tipo de entrega</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                require_once '../ConsultasSW/ConsolidadoOperacionClientesSW.php';
                echo ConsolidadoOperacionClientes($_POST["v1"], $_POST['v3'], $_POST['v4']);
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

pero no le logrado conseguir, lo que requiero es que la imagen este de fondo en la tabla en marca de agua para que no se vuelva complicado comprender el contenido de la tabla...

Answer (score 2):

Con este trozo de código que te envió puedes solucionar tu problema.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .thead{
        background-image: url('tuimagen.jpg');
    }
</style>

<table>
    <thead class="thead">
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Lo que no sabemos es si ese código funcione con el plugin de DataTables por que al parecer este ya tiene uno por default

Comment: Si funciona con DataTables.

Comment: a puesto la imagen solo a los encabezados de las columnas, hay alguna forma de que la imagen esté en el cuerpo de la tabla? queria subir una imagen del resultado para que lo vieran pero no he sabido como...

Comment: Hola @csjo, eso es muy simple, solo coloca el `class="thead"` en `<tbody>`así: `<tbody class="thead">` y eso es todo.

Comment: Lo he probado en el     <tbody> pero al parecer queda atras de la tabla por lo que no se ve, como lo puedo traer al frente?